# Other Users Cannot See Customizations to Global Navigation

Tags: master-page

I customized the global navigation in SharePoint 2010, but my changes are not showing for other users.

What might be causing this?

Comment: If you are going to down vote a new user's question you should at the least explain why so that they can correct potential issues.

Comment: Agreed. This certainly is a valid question.

Comment: Indeed it is, my reading of it was flawed.  I'll upvote it when the timer has expired.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2010 branding - I see it (as site admin) but rest users don't](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20558/sharepoint-2010-branding-i-see-it-as-site-admin-but-rest-users-dont)

Answer (score 1):

Check in / publish the file. This should resolve your issue.

You're seeing the file still in draft mode because of your permissions.

Comment: i did aprove and published, but still only me can see the custom nav

Comment: Did you make the changes in the master page or in CSS? Have you made sure that the file your other users are receiving in the browser is the same file that you edited?

Comment: yes, under look and feel, master page, selected the new master and neww css in style library

Comment: ooooooops, i didnt check in css files, that was good call, after checked in the files inside style lib\glob nav\ all went fine thnx for bringing check in up twice :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Welcome to SPSE.

Answer (score 0):

If you made changes to a master page please ensure that you checked the changes in. I have done this so many times that I cannot count it. Check in the changes and publish.

Comment: i did aprove and published, but still only me can see the custom nav

Answer (score -1):

Check on the sub-sites to see if they're inheriting the parent Global Navigation bar.

If not, you'll need to go back and change it.

Comment: no no, everything is fine in subsites, thats not the question, the question was that other users cannot see the custom global navigation changes

Comment: Fair comment; I misread the question.  Publishing the master page has already been suggested.